# What is the equivalent implementation of service POJOs (jBoss services in jboss 6 AS) of EJB 3.0 in EJB - 3.2

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x, wildfly-8, ejb-3.2

Service POJOs are available which is used to define as jBoss services (in Jboss AS 6) in EJB 3.0 and the tutorial is http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/service/service.html and below are the related annotations.

```
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Depends;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Management;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Service;
```

Similarly, could anyone please tell me the equivalent implementation in EJB 3.2 as I could not find any related jars or tutorials in wildfly 8 application server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality of org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Depends and org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Service can be replaced by:

- [javax.ejb.DependsOn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/DependsOn.html)
- [javax.ejb.Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html)
- [javax.ejb.Startup](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html)

There is no replacement for org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Management